# I would like a trigger that is going to update the Description field on the account with the last notes made on the check-in object

Tags: after

For example, on the account, there is a related list called `check-ins`. Every time a `check-in` is created related to an account, I want to capture details of `check-ins` and need it appended to details to that check-in on the description field to see the details:

```
When
Who
Why
```

This is an example of how it should look like on the description or any long text field :

```
Check-in details for {when} 3/5
{Who}: Rodolfo Ornelas
{Why}: It was a great meeting. Looking forward to coming back

Check-in details for {when} 3/8
{Who}: Rodolfo Ornelas
{Why}: It was a great meeting. Looking forward to coming back

Check-in details for {when} 3/14
{Who}: Rodolfo Ornelas
{Why}: It was a great meeting. Looking forward to coming back
```

My trigger code is :

```
    trigger checkin_trigger on geopointe__Check_In__c (
        before insert, 
        before update, 
        before delete, 
        after insert, 
        after update, 
        after delete, 
        after undelete) {

            /*if (Trigger.isBefore) {
                //call your handler.before method

            } else if (Trigger.isAfter) {
                //call handler.after method

            }*/

            if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
                List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();

                for(geopointe__Check_In__c ci : Trigger.new){
                     if(ci.geopointe__Headline__c != null){
                  //  Decimal d = new Decimal.valueOf(ci.geopointe__When__c);
                  //  Text(Month(DATEVALUE(ci.geopointe__Who__c)));
                    Account a = new Account(Description = ci.geopointe__When__c + ci.geopointe__Who__c + ci.geopointe__Why_Text_Check_Out__c,
Id = ci.geopointe__Account__c);

                    acc.add(a);
                }
              }
                Update acc;
            }
    }
```

Error:-line 27, col 49. Date/time expressions must use Integer or 
        Double or Decimal

ci.geopointe__When__c it is date/time field how to convert date and 
solve above error.

Comment: What is your specific question about this code? If you have an error, please include it and the line number in the body of your question with an [edit]. Otherwise, please describe the behavior that you are struggling with.

Comment: Error:-line 27, col 49. Date/time expressions must use Integer or 
        Double or Decimal

ci.geopointe__When__c it is date/time field how to convert date and 
solve above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Account a = new Account(
    Description = ci.geopointe__When__c + ci.geopointe__Who__c + ci.geopointe__Why_Text_Check_Out__c,
    Id = ci.geopointe__Account__c
);
```

The Description line causes an error because you have an additive (`+`) expression whose first term is a DateTime field. You're trying to add it to, presumably, two String fields.

To do so, you'll need to convert the value of the DateTime to a String, probably by using [`DateTime.format()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm). Do be aware however that this method does the conversion in the time zone of the running user, so values displayed as Strings may differ from values shown on the child record due to Salesforce's automatic time-zone adjustments.

You will probably want to update your code to display a formatted string rather than just concatenating these field values. [`String.format()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#!) will likely be of help to you here.